# Aggregation depends from value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample table

| ID | Invoice_ID | docType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | email |
| 2 | 100 | sms |
| 3 | 200 | email |
| 4 | 200 | email |
| 5 | 300 | sms |

and I have to get results with only rows that have invoices with email and sms docType. For this example its only invoice_id 100

Comment: `HAVING` and a conditional aggregate would be one method. What have you tried? Why didn't it work

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Or _providing_ a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to query those type and count the distinct number of different types that appear:

```sql
SELECT   invoice_id
FROM     invoices
WHERE    doctype IN ('sms', 'email')
GROUP BY invoice_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT doctype) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select invoice_id
from t
where docType in ('email', 'sms')
group by invoice_id
having count(distinct doctype) = 2;
```

Comment: Note that i you have other doc types, this won't give the desired result.

Comment: @Larnu . . . (1) It is curious that you put this comment on this answer rather than the accepted answer.  (2) That is rather big of you to say, given that the question doesn't say what to do in that case.

Comment: 1) Your answer was the accepted answer at the time of my comment (I assume the OP changed it during the grace period). 2) you should know better than to take data at face value. 3) I am happy for you to copy pasta my comment on the new accepted answer.